# Setting variable to some value if server response is undefiend in Angular 2

Tags: angular, ionic2, redux, undefined, reducers

I'm using Angular 2 in combination with Redux (ngrx: reducers and effects) and I am a total beginner in both of them but I must use them. I have request to the server and if there is no values I need to set them to some default value. I have activity and images. Activity is when last motion and/or message have happened and images are links to the images.

Here is code from effects:

```
    @Effect() getActivity$ = this.actions$
      .ofType(DashboardActions.GET_ACTIVITY)
      .withLatestFrom(this.store, (action, state) => ({
        senior: state.senior.globalSenior.id,
        date: action.payload
      }))
      .switchMap((options) => {
        return this.dashboardService.getActivity({
          id: options.senior,
          date: options.date
        })
        .map((res) => ({ type: DashboardActions.GET_ACTIVITY_SUCCESS, payload: res }))
        .catch(() => Observable.of({ type: DashboardActions.GET_ACTIVITY_ERROR }))
      })

    @Effect() getImages$ = this.actions$
      .ofType(DashboardActions.GET_IMAGES)
      .withLatestFrom(this.store, (action, state) => ({
        senior: state.senior.globalSenior.id,
        date: action.payload
      }))
      .switchMap((options) => {
        return this.dashboardService.getImages({
          id: options.senior,
          date: options.date
        })
          .map((res) => ({ type: DashboardActions.GET_IMAGES_SUCCESS, payload: res }))
          .catch(() => Observable.of({ type: DashboardActions.GET_IMAGES_ERROR }))
      })
```

Here is code from reducer:

```
    export interface State {
      activity: any,
      images: any
    }

    const initialState: State = {
      activity: null,
      images: null
    }

    export function reducer (state = initialState, action: Action): State {
      switch (action.type) {
        case DashboardActions.GET_ACTIVITY_SUCCESS:
          return Object.assign({}, state, {
            activity: action.payload
          })

        case DashboardActions.GET_IMAGES_SUCCESS:
          return Object.assign({}, state, {
            images: action.payload
          })

        default:
          return state
      }
    }
```

Here is where I'm using it in html (component) template:

```
        <ion-grid class="dashboard-table">
            <ion-row>
              <ion-col *ngFor="let message of (activity$ | async)?.data[0]" text-center no-padding>
                <span [ngClass]="{'dot-message dot-message--big':(message === 1)}" *ngIf="message"></span>
                <span [ngClass]="{'dot-message':(message !== 1)}" *ngIf="!message"></span>
              </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
            <ion-row>
              <ion-col *ngFor="let motion of (activity$ | async)?.data[1]" text-center no-padding>
                <span [ngClass]="{'dot-motion dot-motion--big':(motion === 1)}" *ngIf="motion"></span>
                <span [ngClass]="{'dot-motion':(motion !== 1)}" *ngIf="!motion"></span>
              </ion-col>
              <ion-col col-6 *ngFor="let image of (images$ | async)" no-padding class="images__col">
                <img (click)="onLittleImageClick(image.data)" [src]="image?.data" />
                <span class="images__time">{{ (activity$ | async)?.last_motion_time | date:'h:mm:a' }}</span>
              </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
        </ion-grid>

     constructor (
       public navCtrl: NavController,
       public modalCtrl: ModalController,
       private store: Store<fromRoot.AppState>
     ) {
       this.activity$ = this.store.select(s => s.dashboard.activity)
       this.images$ = this.store.select(s => s.dashboard.images)
       this.hideSwipeUpButton()
     }
```

And this is what the server returns if there is data:

```
    activity {
      "data":[[1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0]],
      "types":["Message","Motion"],
      "graph_start":0,
      "graph_end":1320,
      "graph_step":120,
      "last_message_time":"2017-07-11T20:17:02.118Z",
      "last_motion_time":"2017-07-11T21:24:02.118Z"
    }
    images {
      data: "https://us.123rf.com/450wm/budabar/budabar1511/budabar151100162/48605730-old-man-sitting-on-bed-and-holding-head-with-hands.jpg?ver=6"
      id: "30230de6-471e-4866-aa6d-ff3e6dd1eee0"
    }
```

So in effect, I'm proceeding to the server options.date which is the date for which I want data. And if there is no data server returns undefined and I can't read that and app crashes. So in that situation, I need to set some default values.

Comment: which part do you want to assign default values. And you can do something like this. var value=undefined || "default"; so the pipe would do it for you

Comment: Catcch this errors `GET_ACTIVITY_ERROR` and `GET_IMAGES_ERROR` in reducer and set a variable in store. Or use ngrx actions$ and do something when actions are fired.

Comment: @LyubimovRoman I can't. I don't get an error because getting is executed without error it just doesn't have values. It is an empty array. Here is console log img:  http://imgur.com/a/srQbd

Comment: @TheophilusOmoregbee I don't quite get your question, can you be more detailed? Where should I put that pipe, can you give a code example?

Comment: @karlo1zg your code is everywhere, so for you to let javascript know which variable to take as default value if what is coming from server is undefined is to use pipes, `let variable = expected _value || default_value` which means if the expected value is undefined take the default value defined by you

Comment: I guess this `(activity$ | async)?.data[0]` is the problem. Try to make another observable with `map()` from the `activity$`. Like `list$ = activity$.filter(activity => !!activity && !!activity.data).map(data => data[0])`. I guess `?.` in the template doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: I solved this problem, posted my solution in an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem. First I defined default values in reducer and set my return values to have Object.assign(). So in my reducer now if there is an empty array returned from the server, reducer will return default values. So finally my reducer looks like this:

```
     const defaultActivityValues = {
       data:[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]],
       types:["Message","Motion"],
       graph_start:0,
       graph_end:0,
       graph_step:0,
       last_message_time:"2017-01-01T20:17:02.118Z",
       last_motion_time:"2017-01-01T21:24:02.118Z"
     }
     export interface State {
       activity: any,
       images: any
     }

     const initialState: State = {
       activity: null,
       images: null
     }

     export function reducer (state = initialState, action: Action): State {
       switch (action.type) {
         case DashboardActions.GET_ACTIVITY_SUCCESS:
           return Object.assign({}, state, {
             activity: Object.assign({}, defaultActivityValues, action.payload)
         })
         case DashboardActions.GET_IMAGES_SUCCESS:
           return Object.assign({}, state, {
             images: action.payload
         })
         default:
           return state
       }
     }
```